# What does #_ mean in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm seeing `#_` around a Clojure project, but this symbol doesn't show up in [clojure docs](https://clojuredocs.org/search?q=%23_), and the REPL won't let me evaluate `(clojure.repl/doc #_)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little digging in search results showed this is *ignore next form*. It's listed as a [reader macro](https://clojure.org/reference/reader#_dispatch).

It was hard enough to find I thought I'd surface it here.

Comment: A dedicated search engine for symbols like this helps alot.  E.g. http://symbolhound.com/?q=%23_+clojure

Comment: Clojure's official docs have a page about "weird characters" including this one. https://clojure.org/guides/weird_characters